# C++: While Loop not working in Linked List

Tags: c++, c++11

Im trying to remove an item from a simple linked list (with a `next` and `value`).

Remove all instances. Sorry for the mistake

Here is my code so far but it seems to only have a linked list that just contains a `nullptr`

What I am doing wrong here?

```
void remove(node<int>*& list1, int val)
{
    while (list1 != nullptr)
    {
        if (list1->value == val)
        {
            node<int>* removed = list1;
            list1 = list1->next;
            delete removed;
        }
        else
            list1 = list1->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not updating the pointer before your node .

Comment: How do i update the pointer. Sorry im new to this

Comment: You should manage to update the `next` pointer of the previous node of interested `removed` node to the next node of the interested removed node.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my code so far but it seems to only have a linked list that just contains a nullptr:

That happens since `list1` is passed by reference and you are changing its value until it is equal to `nullptr`.

Here's one way to fix it.

```
void remove (node<int>*& list1, int val) {

   // If the head of the list contains the value,
   // change the head to point to the next element.
   if(list1->value == val) {
      node<int>* removed = list1;
      list1 = list1->next;
      delete removed;
      return;
   }

   node<int>* prev = list1;
   node<int>* iter = list1;

   // Look for the val in the list
   // Delete the node that has the value.
   // Fix the links.
   while ( iter != nullptr ) {
      if(iter->value == val) {
         prev->next = iter->next;
         delete iter;
         return;
      }
      prev = iter;
      iter = iter->next;
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually this didnt remove every instance but just the first one it saw. Im trying to remove all instance in the list. I took off the return statements but it still didnt work.

Comment: This doesn't remove all nodes with the specified value if the list is allowed to contain nodes with equivalent value.

Comment: @Season, true. The OP said, "remove an item from". If the OP needs to remove all the items that contain the given value, the function definitely needs to be updated.

Comment: @R Sahu, Absolutely. You did solve the question. My comment is intended to leave a reminder. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's rather bad idea to modify argument value while iterating, try this:

```
void remove (node<int>*& head, int val) {
    //empty case
    if(head==nullptr)
        return;
    // front remove - need to reassign head
    if(head->value == val) {
        node<int>* removed = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete removed;
        return; // if you need to delete the first occurence
    }
    // other cases - just jook forward
    node<int>* curr = head;
    while(curr->next != nullptr){
        if(curr->next->value == val){
            node<int>* removed = curr->next;
            curr->next = curr->next->next;
            delete removed;
            return; // if you need to delete the first occurence
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```